# What is the difference between the descendant selector and the :has selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the difference between the [Descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and the [:has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)?

From the documentation:

> **Descendant selector**
>
> *Description:* Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.
>
> A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on, of that element.

> **:has**
>
> *Description:* Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
>
> The expression `$('div:has(p)')` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

Even after reading the explanation, the difference is not clear to me. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: I'm confused.. you just wrote the answer into the question.

Comment: @jAndy: I think the OP just doesn't have a clear understanding of the descriptions given by the docs.

Comment: @BoltClock: I dunno.. looks like he is very aware of the english language.

Comment: @jAndy BoltClock is right, I misunderstood the documentation. Voted to close the question. Please vote too.

Comment: @Markos: If you say so... *-votes to close-* Does my answer help you though? I hope it did.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, it cleared things out. Thanks. Marked it as answer to give you the points.

Comment: I decided to reopen this question as it is in fact a real question. It's clear, useful and will benefit the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The descendant selector in `div p` **selects the `p`** descendants of the `div`.

The `:has()` selector in `div:has(p)` **selects the `div`** if it contains any `p` elements.

The bold parts are all you need to know. The rest can be seen as mere *conditions* as to which elements of those types are selected.

---

In CSS selector terms, the **key selector** is the right-most outer simple selector. The kind of elements that get picked up by jQuery (or by a browser's CSS parser) is the one in the key selector.

In the first selector, the key is `p`, because it's the right-most one, occurring after the descendant combinator (the space). This means a collection of `p` elements will be returned.

In the case of `:has()`, which is a pseudo-class, the `p` is an "inner" simple selector that is *part of the `:has()` pseudo-class*, not part of the entire "outer" selector. The key in that selector is therefore `div`, not `p`. This means a collection of `div` elements will be returned, rather than `p` elements in the first selector.

Answer (score 1):

The `descendants`-selector will select the **actual** descendants, while the `:has`-selector will select the parent element(s) that contain the element within the has().