# jQuery - Why are `li a` and `li:has(a)` different?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In applying `li a` and `li:has(a)` different results show up. But, why is that? Aren't they supposed to do the same thing?

Comment: `li a` matches all A elements that have a LI ancestor; `li:has(a)` matches all LI elements that have an A descendant.

Comment: @Šime Vidas. Can you clarify the difference more? It is still not clear

Comment: Apparently I once wrote a jargon-filled answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067081/jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-the-descendant-selector-and-the-has-selec But the comments on Pekka's answer should be simple enough for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Aren't they supposed to do the same thing?

No. In the first example, you are selecting all `a` inside a `li`; in the second one, you are selecting all the `li` that have an `a`.

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), emphasis mine:

> Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
>
> The expression `$('div:has(p)')` **matches a `<div>`** if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

Comment: When you say: **In the first example, you are selecting all `a` inside a `li`; in the second one, you are selecting all the `li` that have an `a`**, it is still a bit confusing. When I select all `a` inside `li`, doesn't that mean that that `li` has to contain an `a` and otherwise it will not be selected, and which, is the same as the second one? Can you kindly simplify it? Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng With the first selector you will get A elements, with the second selector you'll get LI elements. That's the difference...

Comment: @Med Šime puts it well. Is the difference clear that way? "has" is a property of the `li`. It means literally `give me all li elements that have at least one child of the type "a"`.